# How to apply resolution principle on a product of sums

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Following the book Discrete Mathematics and its Applications By Rosen, in the "foundations of logic and proofs" chapter, I came across this question

---

$\text{Use resolution principle to show that the compound proposition } (p \vee q) \wedge (\lnot p \vee q) \wedge (p \vee \lnot q) \wedge (\lnot p \vee \lnot q) \text{ is not satisfiable.}$

---

I can certainly prove this by using a truth table, but how can I apply resolution? To my knowledge to prove this via the Resolution principle, we must have clauses, which are disjunctions of literals. Each maxterm can be thought of as an individual clause, but how can I work with the whole premise at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to separate the 'maxterms' otherwise it's meaningless to apply the resolution principle. You can apply an algorithm like this :

construct the set $S$ composed by the $4$ 'maxterm' literals :

$$S=\{ p \vee q \ ,\ \lnot p \vee q \ ,\ p \vee \lnot q \ ,\
\lnot p \vee \lnot q\}$$

So applying one time the resolution rule to the first two and last two literals you get $S=\{ q\ ,\ \neg q\}$ , applying again you get $S = \{\}$ so the proposition is not satisfiable.

---

The sense of this algorithm is that you infer $q$ by the first two literals but then you infer $\neg q$ by the last two literals, this means that, to have all the statement to be true, you need $q \land \neg q$, something not possible.

Comment: I have thought of this, but even now we don't exactly have a disjunction of "literals". $(p \wedge q)$ is not a literal I believe.

Comment: mmh I think I have a better way but I need a bit to rewrite it

Comment: They're 'DeMorgan's laws', BTW; it's a proper name, not just 'the morgan law'.

Comment: @debdut I updated with a totally new way, I think this was what it was intended to apply